# Disable Bing Logo in Bing Maps added in Angular 8

Tags: angular, bing-maps

I need to disable "bing" logo on bing maps. I found an option to disable clickable logo in IMapOptions i.e, by setting enableClickableLogo to false. I didn't find the option to hide the logo being displayed. Is there a way to do it?

Version:
"bingmaps": "^2.0.3"

Comment: I think Microsoft doesn't want you to disable the Bing logo from their maps. The offer the service and you use it without a charge. So they can define the rules

Comment: That's correct, it's a violation of the terms of use to disable either the logo or the copyright. See section 2 b) here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/product